# Proper data modelling and visualization in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, data-modeling, data-visualization

This topic may seem broad, but I'm looking for an overview of proper architecture and WPF techniques for data driven applications.

I'm building a data-intensive app that's connected to an Access database.  There are several views of the data onscreen at any given time, and they all update dynamically as the user chooses to interact with any of the views.  One of the views is a 3D map.  Other views include several graphs (D3), a data grid, and a canvas on which I draw the data programmatically, using rectangles and circles (overriding OnRender in my canvas).

My current data model is just my first attempt, and it seems pretty slow.  Basically, as the user interacts with the canvas, a new query gets sent to the Access database, which returns the new set of data to draw in all the views (using an OleDBDataAdapter).  This is pretty slow.  Especially when zooming in and out of the canvas.

I'm hoping for something that can interact with the database in realtime, and draw the data in all the views without any lag.  If this kind of application is not possible with WPF, it'd be good to know that sooner rather than later.  But I assume I'm just doing things wrong.

So I'm hoping someone has tackled this kind of problem before, and can help me get headed in the right direction.

Comment: It would help to know if the bottleneck is the querying itself or the visualization of the query result.  I recommend doing some profiling to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been almost two years since I started this project.  We hired a new WPF developer to help me get it off the ground in the right way, and since then, it has become one of the most successful software projects at my company.  After learning what I've learned, I now know how to answer my own question properly.  So this answer is for me from two years ago, and anyone else just starting out on a WPF project, and don't know what they're doing.

I didn't know anything about **MVVM** (the Model-View-ViewModel pattern) prior to starting this project.  In fact, no one even mentioned this to me when I first posed the question.  This is a must for any WPF project.  It will keep your codebase organized and testable if you follow it religiously.

For my project, the **Model** in MVVM is the layer that talks to the database.  Originally, the plan was to have the database remain open the whole time, and be queried constantly as data was needed.  In the end, the amount of data was so small that we just loaded it into memory and closed the database.   Regardless of how you interact with your data, the rest of the program doesn't care where the data comes from.  It just asks the Model for the data, and it gets served up.

The **ViewModel** is the back-end for each UI piece.  For example, if I am displaying a graph, the ViewModel is the object containing the data needed to display on this graph.  The ViewModel talks to the Model to get the information it needs.  This is written in C#.

The **View** is the UI component containing the graph.  This is written in XAML and uses data bindings to stay in sync/communicate with the ViewModel.  The data bindings are the key to the entire MVVM pattern.

A simple data visualization program might have 10 different Views, each with its own ViewModel.  (I recommend putting each view and viewmodel in their own separate files.  In fact, I would recommend separating your entire project out into several smaller projects: one for the UI (all the XAML files), one for the ViewModels (the C# backend code), one for the Model (data layer, probably C#), another for common utilities, etc.)

As far as data visualization is concerned, we ended up using Visiblox because of its speed and ease of use.  The Visiblox graphs are contained in their respective Views, with data bindings to the ViewModels.  In addition to the Visiblox stuff, we also used DataGrids, and standard input/output controls.  They're all just UI components for displaying data.

The nice thing about this architecture is that the ViewModels simply represent data, and the Views represent the visualization of that data.  They are completely divorced from one another, which makes unit testing a cinch.

I would recommend using one of the existing MVVM frameworks out there, or write your own, like we did.

Obviously, there is a textbook worth of information that could be added to this answer.  This is meant to be a simplified explanation of how MVVM works, and how I would have answered my own question two years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you're currently doing is running a new query and then creating new 'view model' objects based on the data, which subsequently causes new visual elements to be created using data templates.  As you increase the size of the data set and increase the complexity of the visualizations, this can become rather slow.

Assuming that your query returns data with a consistent structure (it is modeled in mostly the same way after each query), you may be able to preserve an object structure and therefore only change properties of your view models, rather than constructing an entire new object hierarchy each time.  This is much faster, but requires you to do some intermediate work to update your view model based on query results, rather than simply creating a brand new view model for the query results.

The details are going to be very specific to your particular problem.  It's also possible I've misunderstood entirely what you're doing.

Comment: Basically, I want to be able to redraw what's in the database at a smooth framerate.  My background is videogames, so I would normally just redraw everything 30 times a second.  But that model doesn't seem to work too well here.  I figure there must be a better way to bind to the database and have a live view of the data being drawn every time the data range is modified (like zooming).

Comment: Maybe my problem is too specific, but I figured someone would have dealt with this already that might have some insight.  Or perhaps this is just the nature of the beast, and it's going to be slow if I want to use WPF.  I'm still new to the WPF way of doing things, so it's possible I'm not modeling the data right.